# Dynamic div does not work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Last year I published this one page site: www.rofeengenharia.com.br

In the Portifolio page if you click on "Abrir" it loads a dynamic div with javascript over the Portifolio page. In Safari and Firefox it is still working, but it stopped working in Chrome (it was working in Chrome too when I published it).

Here is part of the code:

The place where the dynamic div is loaded and the link to open it (onClick):

```
<DIV id="projeto_selecionado" style="position:absolute; z-index:20000; background:#ffffff;">

</DIV>          
<!-- OBRA 1 -->
<DIV class="view view-sixth">
  <IMG width="100%" height="auto" style="float:left;" src="images/portifolio/obra01/obra01_thumb_01.jpg" alt="Obra 01" />
  <DIV class="mask">
    <H2>Condomínio Jardim Acapulco</H2>
    <P>Manutenção executada pela ROFE no litoral sul de São Paulo.</P>
    <A href="#" class="info" onClick="exibir_projeto01()">Abrir</A>
  </DIV>
</DIV><!-- view -->
```

And the javascript file:

```
function exibir_projeto01()
{
$('<div/>').addClass("newdiv")
                .html('<DIV id="projeto_selecionado">\
...
...
...
</DIV><!-- container_projeto_01 -->')
                .appendTo($("#projeto_selecionado"))
                .hide()
                .fadeIn(1000);

// Não deixa a pagina voltar para o topo quando clica no link
event.preventDefault();
}
```

Anyone knows how to make it work in Chrome again?

Comment: I had a look at your site. It's very hard to debug. You are using almost everything in the 'wrong' way.

Comment: Put your div with all the html somewhere else in the page maybe and then show() it after you have it appearing properly.

I know this might come across as cruel but, you really should re-write your site in my opinion. Also consider putting a min-width on the site because at around 900px across things become unusable and buttons go missing.

Good luck! x

Comment: Thanks Aaria but I can't put it all in the same page. There are more than 50 images. It's to heavy. That is why I'm loading it dynamically.

Comment: There are good lazy-loading javascript plugins out there - have you considered using them? x

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery - remove the inline onclick and do this instead - also you try to add something with ID `#projeto_selecionado` to itself

```
$(".info").on("click",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('<div/>').addClass("newdiv")
            .html('<DIV>\
   ...\
   ...\
   ...\
    </DIV>')
            .appendTo("#projeto_selecionado")
            .hide()
            .fadeIn(1000);
});
```

WITHOUT html comments!